# CUDA errors: identifier "(global/device)" is undefined, no suitable conversion, 

Tags: cuda, device, global

Im doing a project on Photon mapping. I coded raytracer part and it ran successfully on CPU. Now im doing the same on GPU(through ssh).

im getting the following errors

> ```
>     nvcc -c -lSDL -lGL -lGLU AntTweakBar.a gpuRayTracer.cu
> gpuRayTracer.cu(44): error: identifier "raytracer" is undefined
>
> gpuRayTracer.cu(53): error: no suitable conversion function from
> ```
>
> "Float3" to "void *" exists
>
> ```
> gpuRayTracer.cu(55): error: no suitable conversion function from
> ```
>
> "Float3" to "void *" exists
>
> ```
> gpuRayTracer.cu(76): error: identifier "GPUsub" is undefined
>
> gpuRayTracer.cu(77): error: identifier "GPUnormalize" is undefined
>
> gpuRayTracer.cu(78): error: identifier "GPUcross" is undefined
>
> gpuRayTracer.cu(80): error: calling a host function from a
> ```
>
> **device**/_*global*_ function is not allowed
>
> ```
> gpuRayTracer.cu(90): error: identifier "GPUmul" is undefined
>
> gpuRayTracer.cu(95): error: calling a host function from a
> ```
>
> **device**/_*global*_ function is not allowed
>
> ```
> gpuRayTracer.cu(95): error: identifier "GPUadd" is undefined
>
> gpuRayTracer.cu(192): error: calling a host function from a
> ```
>
> **device**/_*global*_ function is not allowed
>
> ```
> 15 errors detected in the compilation of
> ```
>
> "/tmp/tmpxft_0000432c_00000000-4_gpuRayTracer.cpp1.ii"
>       .
>       make: *** [gpuRayTracer.o] Error 2

***gpuRayTracer.cu***
 line 44,53, 55(errors) are marked in the below code

Float3 used below is a structure containing 3 float variables(x,y,z coordinates)

```
void Scene::GPUrayTracer(){

Object *d_objectList[OBJ_MAX];
GLubyte         * d_pixels;
int *d_Width, *d_Height;
Float3 *d_eye,*d_lookAt;
int *d_objectCount;
size_t size1=sizeof(Float3);
size_t size2=sizeof(int);
size_t size3=sizeof(GLubyte);
//size_t size4=sizeof(Object);

cudaMalloc(&d_eye,size1);
cudaMalloc(&d_lookAt,size1);
cudaMemcpy(d_eye,&this->eye,size1,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMemcpy(d_lookAt,&this->lookAt,size1,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


cudaMalloc(&d_objectCount,size2);
cudaMemcpy(d_objectCount,&this->objectCount,size2,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);



cudaMalloc(&d_Width,size2);
cudaMalloc(&d_Height,size2);
cudaMemcpy(d_Width,&this->screenWidth,size2,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMemcpy(d_Height,&this->screenHeight,size2,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


cudaMalloc(&d_pixels,size3);
cudaMemcpy(d_pixels,&this->pixels,size3,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


cudaMalloc((void **)&d_objectList,
(sizeof(this->objectList)));
cudaMemcpy(d_objectList,
&this->objectList,
sizeof(this->objectList),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

line 44:raytracer<<<1,500>>>(d_pixels,d_Width,d_Height,
d_objectList,d_eye,d_lookAt);

cudaMemcpy((this->objectList),&d_objectList,sizeof(this-
>objectList),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(this->pixels,&d_pixels,size3,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


cudaMemcpy((int *)this->screenWidth,&d_Width,size2,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaMemcpy((int *)this->screenHeight,&d_Height,size2,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaMemcpy((int *)this->objectCount,&d_objectCount,size2,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaMemcpy(


line:53   (void *)this->eye,
(void *)&d_eye,sizeof(d_eye),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
line:55  cudaMemcpy(this->lookAt,(void *)&d_lookAt,sizeof(d_lookAt),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


}



__global__ void raytracer( unsigned char *out_data,const int screenWidth,const int screenHeight,Object * objectList,Float3 eye,Float3 lookAt,int objectCount)
{
int x = blockDim.x * BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.x;
        int y = blockDim.y * BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.y;

        [b]//code goes here[/b]
}

__device__ float GPUffminf(float a, float b){



if(a<b)
        return a;

return b;


}



__device__ float GPUffmaxf(float a, float b){


        if(a>b)

        return a;

return b;

}





__device__ float GPUmag(Float3 a){

float res;

res=a.x*a.x+a.y*a.y+a.z*a.z;

res=sqrt(res);

return res;

}



__device__ Float3 GPUnormalize(Float3 a){

Float3 res;

float magn=mag(a);

if(magn!=0){

magn=(float)1.0/magn;

res.x=a.x*magn;

res.y=a.y*magn;

res.z=a.z*magn;

return res;

}

return a;



}

__device__ Float3 GPUcross(Float3 a ,Float3 b){

Float3 res;

res.x=a.y*b.z-a.z*b.y;

res.y=a.z*b.x-a.x*b.z;

res.z=a.x*b.y-a.y*b.x;

return res;

}

__device__  float GPUdot(Float3 a,Float3 b){

return (float)(a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y + a.z*b.z);

}



__device__  Float3 GPUsub(Float3 a,Float3 b){

Float3 res;

res.x=a.x-b.x;

res.y=a.y-b.y;

res.z=a.z-b.z;

return res;

}

__device__ Float3 GPUadd(Float3 a,Float3 b){

Float3 res;

res.x=a.x+b.x;

res.y=a.y+b.y;

res.z=a.z+b.z;

return res;

}





__device__ Float3 GPUmul(Float3 a,float b){

Float3 res;

res.x=a.x*b;

res.y=a.y*b;

res.z=a.z*b;

return res;

}
```

wats wrong in the code??

apart from this i have few questions

***The order in which .cu/.cpp files are compiled..is it matter??
*Should the kernel be invoked only from main.cpp??
*If so, should a .cu file consists of only global/device functions ??**

Comment: First, start by defining prototypes for all of your device functions at the top of the file like that: "\_\_global\_\_ void raytracer(unsigned char,int,int,Object*,Float3,Float3,int);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Okay first of all, you can put any
>   C/C++ function in **.cu** files other
>   than global/device functions. Neither
>   does the order of compilation matter.
>
> 1. For this error: no suitable conversion function from "Float3" to
>      "void *" exists
>
>    you need to do 
>      (void**)

instead of

> (void*)

For errors like these: gpuRayTracer.cu(76): error: identifier

> "GPUsub" is undefined
>
> you need to define GPUsub function
>   before the functions that calls it in
>   the .cu file. Just move the function
>   definition on top of the file.
>
> For errors like this: calling a host function from a device/*global* function is not
>   allowed
>
> okay, you can't call any function that
>   executes on CPU (doesn't have a
>   **device** or **global** identifier in it) from a device or global function.
>
> Here's what you need to do to make
>   life easy.
>
> Define each function in a separate .cu
>   file and use header file for their
>   decelerations. You should have one HOST
>   function that executes all the
>   pipeline, it can call gpu as well as
>   cpu functions.